# what constructor for Swift UIAction takes a trailing closure?

Tags: swift, uikit

I am using the code below successfully but every time I create a UIAction like this I wonder why I don't see any constructors that take a trailing closure when I go to reference on the UIAction class.

```
    filterView.categoryButton.addAction(UIAction {[unowned self] _ in
        self.displayCategoryMenu()
    }, for: .touchUpInside)
```

this doesn't appear to be the right constructor:

```
public convenience init(title: String = "", image: UIImage? = nil, identifier: UIAction.Identifier? = nil, discoverabilityTitle: String? = nil, attributes: UIMenuElement.Attributes = [], state: UIMenuElement.State = .off, handler: @escaping UIActionHandler)
```

why can I create a UIAction using "UIAction {   }"?

Comment: "this doesn't appear to be the right constructor" Why? There is only one initialiser. **It has to be that one.** The trailing closure is for the very last `handler` parameter.

Comment: And because all the other params have default values UIAction { } is UIAction(handler: { }) using the convenience init with default values for all the other arguments

Comment: oh wow I'm dumb. didn't look at the end at all. just glanced at it and saw too many parameters and didn't even think of defaults. thank you

Comment: `[weak self]` is usually  safer than `[unowned self]`, because the `unowned` version presuppose self can never become nil and could crash if it does.